# How to access the project documentation pages created using Gdoc in grails

Tags: grails, documentation

I followed the tutorial on the [grails documentation](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.6%20Project%20Documentation) was successfully able to create project specific documentation pages by running the following command

```
grails doc
```

I was able to view the HTML pages from my desktop and I found them on the following directory:
..\target\docs\index.html

I was wondering how to access these generated HTML pages from the server. What is the URL to view them from the server?
I tried the following URL but did not work?

http://localhost:8080//docs/index.html

Also, the grails documentation states that the command will output an docs/manual/index.html
 page. Rather I found the index.html page on the following directory:
..\target\docs\index.html

Can anyone help me in this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're not built to be viewed from the running application, so they're not automatically exposed as a url. But you can move them to the `web-app` folder and they'll be accessible.

You can also configure the build location to be under `web-app`. Add this line to `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
grails.project.docs.output.dir = 'web-app/docs'
```